# How do I get rid of this Danish iWeb homepage?

Tags: google-chrome, iweb

Whenever I reboot my Mac (formerly 2009 13" MBP, recently migrated to a 2015 13" MBP) my Google Chrome homepage shows the following Danish iWeb help page. I no longer have iWeb installed, but I imagine it's followed me onto my new MBP via the Migration Assistant.

I've verified that my home page is setup correctly in chrome and if I close the Chrome window and re-open it my home page will be correct, so this problem only occurs **once per boot**.

Here's the window that I'm talking about: [image: Danish iWeb]

I've never had my Mac set to Danish, but this Mac has gone through several family members and several OSX updates through the years.

Comment: Is this a fresh OS X install?

Comment: To clarify - does Chrome _open itself_ on login/reboot and display this page, or when you manually invoke the Chrome app _after_ a fresh reboot?

Comment: This is a fresh install, but the Migration Assistant was used to restore from Time Machine and Applications/System Settings were both checked. I might be onto something with some help from another friend regarding iWeb.app, a remnant from ages ago. I'm currently hunting in the "Login Items" area. @IconDaemon it opens by itself. Good call. This was also what my other friend had asked. We've removed a suspect html item from the "Login Items" and are rebooting now.

Answer (score 2):

As both @IconDaemon and another user suggested, I noticed the MBP was just opening Chrome without the user asking it, it was on boot. This led to the "Login Items" prefpane under User Accounts which looked like this:

[image: Mysterious html file]

How did she get that `24538.html` there... Once it was removed (via the minus sign), problem solved. I had no idea you could set a web page to open on login...

We cleaned up a bunch of these items after testing the removal of just the html file. Removing just the html file worked.